# Socialengine 4.8.6 on AWS (EC2, RDS (MYSQL/INNODB), S3 and CLOUDFRONT) - White Screen on Startup/ possible INNODB issue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb, amazon-rds, socialengine

Socialengine 4.8.6 - shows a 'white screen' on startup, only the sesystem.com/phpmyadmin and sesystem.com/install can be accessed via the browser.

Problem started: 
I needed a new database with a copy of production data to test a new upgrade (Socialengine 4.8.9). I used PHPMYADMIN to copy the production db(PROD) to a new developement db (COPYOFPROD), both databases reside on AWS RDS, same instance and user/password, and both connect via INNODB.

Changed social/application/settings/database.php on my system from PROD to COPYOFPROD to test the database was correct (Yes - not very clever with aproduction system!). Got a white screen when trying to access the system via the browser with the new database.

Reverted the single config change on /application/settings/database.php to the original setting.  The White screen remains and looking at the Socialengine error logs, it reports it doesn't recognise the PROD database anymore. No other file in the Socialengine install directories have changed.

Status : 
Access to the RDS databases on phpmyadmin is ok
Accessing socialengine,  www.sesystem.com/install then select 'requirements and redundancy check'  the System reports the following:

MySQL                              'OK'

MySQL 4.1                          'Unable to check. No database adapter was provided.'

MySQL InnoDB Storage Engine       'Unable to check. No database adapter was provided.'

I therefore summarise that i have crashed the INNODB service with my actions. I understand the service is sensitive and will crash if you change config entries.

I have read that the INNODB log files need to be removed before the service will resume, i have tried the procedure of removing the ib_logfiles and restarting mysql. 
Result :  mysql start [ok],  the ib_logfiles  are recreated,  but when i try Socialengine it still has a 'white screen' and still reports 'No database adaptor'.

My questions are :

1) How do i check INNODB services are running correctly on AWS EC2/RDSMYSQL? Note: I'm using Terminal from a OSX Machine connecting to EC2 via the standard ECUSER and a pemkey combination.

2) How do i access mysqlmonitor on AWS RDS with the appropriate permission problems to make checks on INNODB status.  Currently the system reports -  you need 'PROCESS' rights when trying show status commands.

3) Which are the best logs in Socialengine to see why the whitescreen is happening and are there any tips - because i am only assuming this is the INNODB issue but i need to confirm it.

I am a novice, so not sure what my next steps are..

Many Thanks

Comment: Yep that was the solution to the problem 100%, Many Thanks. Some how the quotes i used in database.php for the database instance name were incorrect. i sat in front of the screen for 14 hours before i finally figured it out.

Comment: After finally loading up a copy of my production to my development system, i upgraded to 4.8.9 and tested it. Finally moved it to production about 6 hours ago and everything is running smoothly. Nice work at Social Engine, upgrade was super smooth. Users have been hammering my socialengine site with postings of embedded youtube videos - obviously they missed that feature a lot prior to upgrade  - site traffic has trebled in only a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue comes with the fact that overwrote too much in the database.php settings file.  Check out `database.sample.php` for all required setting keys, here it is below for reference:

```
defined('_ENGINE') or die('Access Denied'); return array(
  'adapter' => 'mysqli',
  'params' => array(
    'host' => "rds connection string",
    'username' => "rds user",
    'password' => "rds password",
    'dbname'   => "se database",
    'charset'  => 'UTF-8',
    'adapterNamespace' => 'Zend_Db_Adapter',
  ),
  'isDefaultTableAdapter' => true,
  'tablePrefix' => "engine4_",
  'tableAdapterClass' => "Engine_Db_Table",
);
```

In the future, I highly suggest using AWS/RDS built in "snapshot" feature.

### Upgrade Test Steps

1. Take an RDS Snapshot
2. Take an EC2 instance snapshot (keep instance running)
3. Launch new RDS instance from snapshot
4. Launch new EC2 Instance from snapshot
5. change database on the new instance (verify its working)
6. apply an update
7. verify its working and ensure everything is peachy

   ### To now upgrade your live install (this assumes you use s3 for your storage):
8. take a pre-upgrade RDS snapshot
9. on your new upgraded SE Instance, remember, all settings should match the old system.
10. Switch db credentials to live db
11. re-run database upgrade script
12. Switch ELB or Elastic IP or however you are handling traffic to the new instance.